# Alt+Tab and switching workspaces from full screen applications freeze

Tags: games, steam, workspaces, application-switcher

I'm currently using Ubuntu 16.04 on my Lenovo Thinkpad and keep running into the following problem: When I try to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> out of many applications in full screen mode, the system becomes unresponsive to both keyboard and mouse inputs without actually changing what is displayed. Some processes seem to keep running, as sound usually continues playing and the mouse cursor still moves, but I am unable to actually do anything.

I first noticed this in a number of games on Steam, but it also happened with image viewer earlier, I don't recall any other non-games applications though.
Curiously, in the case of "Electronic Super Joy" the game still responded to my Xbox controller, but when I tried to close it by that means I got stuck on the closing screen of the game. I haven't tried using the controller with other games when they froze in this way.

I recently tried circumventing the issue by using separate workspaces, but the same problem occurred on switching from full screen applications.

Let me know if and how I can provide you with more information to diagnose the problem.